# Trying to get a SQL return before entering variable information for Powershell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I’m trying to create an install script using PS that will first run a few queries on a SQL Server database and return the results.

The user is then prompted to enter variables, based on that SQL Server returns.

Next the install will begin by passing these variables to more SQL commands.

I'm confused about this part.

I first get prompted to enter my SiteID before the query is visible in ISE. Once I hit enter, then I see the results of the query.

However, if I add a wildcard to the query, then the query shows first, where I can then make my selection for the SiteID.

```
$SqlQueryOrg = "SELECT ID, Name, Description, Code FROM sysadm.Organization"
```

vs.

```
$SqlQueryOrg = "SELECT ID, Name, Description, Code, * FROM sysadm.Organization"
```

Full code:

```
$SQLServer = "localhost\INSTANCE"   
$SQLDBName = "DBNAME"  
$uid ="sa"  
$pwd = "myPassWord"  

function getSiteInfo() {  
    $SqlQueryOrg = "SELECT ID, Name, Description, Code FROM sysadm.Organization"  

    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand  
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQueryOrg  
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection  
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter  
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd  
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet  
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)  
    $Output = $DataSet.Tables[0]  
    Write-Output $Output  
}
try {  
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection  
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated  Security = True; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;";  
    getSiteInfo;  

    $siteId = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the SiteID of the Organization'   
    # Based on the entry, do more work...  

} catch {  
    $w = "Error connecting to the SQL Server database."  
    $w | Write-Warning  
    Break  
}
```

Comment: Are yo asking how to filter data returned from in a SQL query? With a `WHERE`.

Comment: Change `getSiteInfo;` to `getSiteInfo |Out-Host` to force synchronous output rendering

Comment: Which version of PowerShell? `$PSVersionTable` Is the SqlServer or SQLPS module being used? If integrated security is used, do credentials need to be specified? Have you tried `Invoke-Sqlcmd`? ISE still runs, but has little or no future. Have you tried VS Code? https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: Thanks, this was the fix: getSiteInfo | Out-Host;
Looks like I’m using PS v5.1, but now that you mention it, I’ll have to make sure this works for the ISE or the PS Command line.
I have not tried Invoke-Sqlcmd to access SQL-Server, is there a benefit using the invoke?
Yes, there is a where clause and most of my queries will also have an inner join.
I can’t use VS because we must make this a script that we can change it on the fly if needed, where if we do that in VS, it has to go through change control.

Comment: You can use Visual Studio Code to manage your PS scripts - which can use PS 7 instead of 5.1.  Invoke-SqlCmd allows access to all of the commands that SQLCMD command line utility uses.